# Configure Apache HTTP 2.2 for PUT method

Tags: c#, apache, httpwebrequest

I've written code for file upload and download using the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes in C# with the Apache HTTP server v2.2. In code, I am using 'request.method = "PUT"', so I want to configure my httpconfig file to support the PUT method. I write the PUT method script as

```
<Location "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/output">
    <Dav On
    <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PUT>
    <Allow from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

That's not working. How do make it work?

Comment: At program output :(405) The method not allowed

Comment: this question is not about code - it is about configuring Apache which is better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring it like below. You will need a proper path to the program/handler that will process PUT requests.

```
<Location "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/output">
Dav On
<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PUT>
<Allow from all>
</LimitExcept>
Script PUT {path to PUT handler}
</Location>
```

Comment: Does your C# program have a handler setup to process PUT requests?